# Converting a .mp4 file throws "Resampling with input channels greater than 2 unsupported." error

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flv, resampling

I am trying to convert a mp4 file into flv with 2 audio channels & sample rate of 44.1 Khz (because .flv does not allow higher than that). [Here is the pastebin for the error.](http://pastebin.com/WbwWkJP6)
As seen from the console output, I am using the latst build of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are resampling. Ffmpeg doesn't support resampling for 5+1 input channels, only for mono and stereo. Try converting it without specifying a sample rate and it might work. So try omitting the sample rate, that way the audio won't be resampled. Alternatively you might try just copying the audio stream (use -vcodec copy). Again the audio won't be resampled. You might also try first converting it to 2 channels intermediate file, and then resampling, but I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: Ok. I think the problem if I dont mention any sample rate is that flv supports only 3 audio sample rates, 44.1 Khx being the highest. If I dont mention it might cause an error on unsupported sampling rate.

Comment: Actually I just checked it out and gave the error when I did not specify any sampling rate. Here is the error > http://pastebin.com/8n2Eavt7

Comment: See this link: http://muzso.hu/2009/02/25/downsampling-multichannel-audio-5.1-into-stereo-2-channels-with-ffmpeg. I haven't tried it so I don't know if it really works, but it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I've installed [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) from RPM, but then I took the lates version from [here](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/) and it worked like a charm!

One note though, some flags have been changed, for example `-sameq` should be `-qscale 0` when using the new version, so keep in mind that it needs to be tested well before using it on production environments.

Answer (score 0):

You need a newer version of FFMPEG. I got mine by downloading WinFF from Video Help over at http://www.videohelp.com/software/WinFF then I proceeded to use the ffmpeg.exe that the front end came with.